# Where do non-db "actions" fit in MVC? eg. send email, consume webservices, etc

Tags: model-view-controller

Just trying to solidify my understanding of the MVC pattern.

My gut is saying that these actions are part of the controller layer, but what if it is an external rest service, and itself represents a "model"?

Would you have more than one model? or re-architect to include the multiple models in your singular model?

What about sending email? It doesn't necessarily impact any application data?

Comment: All components ensuring the transfer of entities' momentarily state/data to/from various storage systems or external services should reside or be abstracted (like [this](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html), or [this](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html), etc) in the [domain model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html). The "actions" consuming them should belong to the components of the [application's service layer](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html), e.g. to its services.

Comment: The service layer should be seen as the boundary between the domain model and the UI layer. A controller, as a UI layer's construct, should only delegate the user request to an application service... I hope [this](http://confreaks.tv/videos/rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years), [this](https://vimeo.com/101106002) and [this](https://codurance.com/videos/2015-04-24-interaction-driven-design/) (as the updated version of the 2nd resource) will help.